# How to find regex for multiple conditions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to find regex which would find below matches. I would replace these with blank. I am able to create regex for few of these conditions individually, but I am not able to figure out how to create one regex for all of these

Strings:

```
song1 artist  (SiteWithMp3Keyword.com).mp3
02.song2 | siteWithdownloadKeyword.in 320 Kbps
  song3 [SitewithDjKeyword.in] 128kbps.mp3
```

Output

```
song1 artist.mp3
song2
song3.mp3
```

Criteria for match:

1. Case Insensitive
2. Find Strings with particular keyword and remove whole word, even if inside any braces
3. Find kpbs keyword and remove it along with any number before it (128/320)
4. if string ends in .mp3, keep it as it is.
5. Remove junk characters (like | ) and replace _ with space.
6. Remove number if present at start of string, like 001_ 02. etc.
7. Trim whitespaces before and after remaining string

Example Regex for 2.

```
\S+(mp3|dj|download)\S+
```

https://regex101.com/r/nxp4d3/1

Comment: I would assume that everything following a demarcation character like `[ | ( ` is junk except for `.mp3`, so I'd match for that, along with junk at the beginning and end of the string. That could look like this: `^(?:\d+\W*|\s+)|\s+$|\s*[[(|](?:(?!\.mp3).)*`, which is `beginning|end|non-mp3`. You'd have to replace any underscores with a blank space in a second substitution. Edit: here is an example: https://regex101.com/r/86aoEC/1

Comment: It's awesome. I tested it for all the scenarios that I have and it is working for all of them. 
Do you mind putting it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex ....
Find:`^[0-9. ]*(song\d+ (\w+ )?).*?(\.mp3 ?)?$`
Replace with:`$1$3`

[image]

P.S , if this code doesn't solve your problem,  please share a sample of your real data,  so someone well better understand you,
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

For the example data, you might use:

```
^\h*(?:\d+\W*)?(\w+(?:\h+\w+)*).*?(\.mp3)?\h*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\h*` Match optional leading spaces
- `(?:\d+\W*)?` Match 1+ digits followed by optional non word characters
- `(\w+(?:\h+\w+)*)` Capture **group 1**, match word characters optionally repeated with a space in between
- `.*?` Match any character except a newline, as least as possible
- `(\.mp3)?` Optionally capture `.mp3` in **group 2**
- `\h*` Match optional trailing spaces
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LETcWD/1)

Replace with capture group 1 and group 2

```
$1$2
```

[image]